# Search data in two datagrids at same time

Tags: c#, search, rowfilter

I have this two datagrids where JMBGvlasnika is in both of them same as BrojSasije.

For search I use this code:

```
 DataView DV = new DataView(dbdt);
                    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("JMBGvlasnika LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
                    korisniciDataGridView.DataSource = DV;
```

Loading tables code:

```
private void svikorisnici_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT * FROM Korisnici", konekcija);
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" SELECT * FROM vozilo", konekcija);
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                dbdt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdt);
                BindingSource kbs = new BindingSource();

                kbs.DataSource = dbdt;
                korisniciDataGridView.DataSource = kbs;
                sda.Update(dbdt);


                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sda1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                DataTable dbdt1 = new DataTable();
                sda1.Fill(dbdt1);
                BindingSource kbs1 = new BindingSource();

                kbs1.DataSource = dbdt1;
                voziloDataGridView.DataSource = kbs1;
                sda1.Update(dbdt1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Problem is when I search by JMBGvlasnika I get search results only for 1st table

image link http://ge.tt/999Igxm/v/0?c

If I try to do this:

```
DataView DV1 = new DataView(dbd1t);
DV1.RowFilter = String.Format("JMBGvlasnika LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
voziloDataGridView.DataSource = DV1;
```

And start searching I get empty 2nd table, and if I delete what I wrote 2nd table is not filtering.

Can someone help me to make search in both datagrids in same time ?